# Confused with the return values while overloading the operators

Tags: c++

In the code below, I don't understand the value that gets returned after the invocation of the operator. The value that is being returned is of type (char*) and the type of the variable that it is initialized to is String. Does C++ take care of internal conversion?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string.h> //for strcpy()

class String //user-defined string type
{
private:
    enum { SZ = 80 }; //size of all String objects
    char str[SZ]; //holds a C-string
public:
    String() //no-arg constructor
    { 
        str[0] = '\0'; 
    }
    String( char s[] ) //1-arg constructor
    { 
        strcpy(str, s);     // convert C-string to String
    } 
   void display() const //display the String
   {
        cout << str; 
   }
   operator char*() //conversion operator
   { 
       return str;     //convert String to C-string 
   } 
};

int main()
{
    String s1; //use no-arg constructor
    char xstr[] = "Joyeux Noel! ";            //create and initialize C-string
    s1 = xstr;                               //use 1-arg constructor
    s1.display();                            //display String
    String s2 = "Bonne Annee!";              //uses 1-arg constructor
    s1=(char*)s2;
    cout << s1; 
    cout << endl; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Indentation and empty lines may not matter for the compiler, but they matter very much for people attempting to read your code. Please try to indent the code and add some empty lines to split it up into paragraphs.

Comment: And please point out the specific lines of code you wonder about. Please try to be more specific about what you're asking about.

Comment: Your `str` member is an array of `char`, which can 'decay' to a `char*` pointer: when your `char*` operator returns `str` it is actually returning the address of the first element (i.e. pointer to the array start). No conversion, *per se*, is done.

Comment: I hope you are aware that this string class of yours has a lot of other problems aside from the one you asked about (and I mean aside from the obvious, reimplementing functionality already in the standard library). If you wonder about what they might be, [codereview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) might be a good place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

For starters in this statement

```
s1 = xstr; //use 1-arg constructor
```

there is used the default copy-assignment or move-assignment operator implicitly defined by the compiler (in the case of your class definition the compiler should declare implicitly the both assignment operators). That is at first a temporary object of the type String is created using the 1-arg constructor and this object is assigned to the object s1 by copying its data members.

The same occurred in this statement.

```
s1=(char*)s2;
```

That is there is used the default copy-assignment or move-assignment operator. At first a temporary object of the type String is created using the conversion constructor that accepts an object of the type `char *`. And then this object is assigned to the object s1.

More precisely in this expression

```
(char*)s2
```

there is explicitly called the conversion operator

operator char*() //conversion operator
   { 
       return str;     //convert String to C-string 
   }

So the expression has the type `char *`.

There is no assignment operator in the class that accepts as the right operand an object of the type `char *`. However in the class there is declared the implicit conversion constructor

```
String( char s[] ) //1-arg constructor
{ 
    strcpy(str, s);     // convert C-string to String
}
```

that can convert an object of the type `char *` to an object of the type `String`.

After such a conversion the default copy assignment or move-assignment operator can be applied and the created temporary object is assigned to the object s1.

Comment: Thanks, viad. I've understood it now